# AWS S3 PHP getObject standard example causing fatal error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fatal-error, method-call

I have some code that looks exactly like this:

```
$result = $client->getObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key'    => 'data.txt',
   'SaveAs' => '/tmp/data.txt'
));
```

its one of the examples listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObject

unfortunately I get this fatal error:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for AmazonS3::get_object() in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-    for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 1489
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: filename in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 1495
PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 1042
PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 1043
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 548
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'S3_Exception' with message 'S3 does not support "Array" as a valid bucket name. Review "Bucket Restrictions and Limitations" in the S3 Developer Guide for more information.' in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php:548
Stack trace:
0 /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php(1530): AmazonS3->authenticate(Array, Array)
1 [internal function]: AmazonS3->get_object(Array)
2 /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/sdk.class.php(436): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
3 /var/www/CronJobs/leefomatic/index.php(70): CFRuntime->__call('getObject', Array)
4 /var/www/CronJobs/leefomatic/index.php(70): AmazonS3->getObject(Array)
5 {main}
thrown in /var/www/CronJobs/aws-sdk-for-php/services/s3.class.php on line 548
```

in my script I am currently listObject, copy_object and delete_option just fine. Any thoughts as to why a fatal error comes up on a getObject?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your bucket name? Are you using latest aws php sdk?

Comment: Why would the bucket name matter? I am using aws sdk php 2 here is my exact syntax: 

    $result = $s3->getObject(array(
       'Bucket' => 'lief4000videobucket',
       'Key'    => $file,
       'SaveAs' => '/tmp/'.$file
    ));

I var_dump($file) right before I call getObject and it comes out as a string.

Comment: Can you please echo $file? so that we know either your variable have right filename.

Comment: The error log tells you what's wrong `'S3 does not support "Array" as a valid bucket name.`

Comment: I have echoed the $file and var_dump($file) and it is a string of a object that exists in that bucket.

Comment: You are actually using SDK 1.x. What made you think you are using SDK 2.x? How did you install it? I'd like to know so I can help improve the process and prevent this from happening to others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the [SDK 2.x](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) documentation with [SDK 1.x](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php) code. The filenames (e.g., `s3.class.php`, `sdk.class.php`) output in the error block you have shown definitely indicate that you are using SDK 1.x code. You either need to install the newer and better supported SDK 2.x ([here are some instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html)), or use the [SDK 1.x docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/).